# wxPython Custom Dialog loading incorrectly

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a custom dialog to display information. It is activated on a button press, and that mechanism is working perfectly. However, the dialog itself is broken. Any help is appreciated.

```
import wx

class ForgotPass(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ForgotPass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.title = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='Forgotten Your Password?', style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.title.SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, underline=True))  # Underlined & Bold
        self.sizer.Add(self.title)

        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Contact 'TheHiguty' via ingame PM to have your password reset!", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.text)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetSize((200, 150))
        self.SetTitle('Forgotten Your Password')
        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    ForgotPass(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However rather than displaying the text correctly, I get this:

[image]

Any help to fix this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You create your dialog but don't do anything with it (no variable, no `app.SetTopWindow()`. Was it intended?

Comment: It's called from  a button press from a wx.Frame, this is just a shorter example to display the problem. Do I still need those things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `self.sizer.Fit(self.panel)` after `self.SetSizer(self.sizer)` to fix the problem. 
Although, if you do so, you'll find that the horizontal width is too small, so you might want to expand that. Complete code with fix:

```
import wx

class ForgotPass(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ForgotPass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.title = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='Forgotten Your Password?', style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.title.SetFont(wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, underline=True))  # Underlined & Bold
        self.sizer.Add(self.title)

        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Contact 'TheHiguty' via ingame PM to have your password reset!", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.text)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self.panel)
        self.SetSize((400, 150))
        self.SetTitle('Forgotten Your Password')
        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    ForgotPass(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Although, there is a way to create dialogs that look cleaner and looks more native to whatever OS the program is run on: use [wx.MessageBox](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/)

Here's a simple example:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="Test")
        self.sizer.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.password_dialog, self.button)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        self.SetTitle('Test')
        self.SetSize((100, 100))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def password_dialog(self, event):
        wx.MessageBox(
            'Contact `TheHiguty` blah blah blah',
            'Forgotten your password?',
            wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MainWindow(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is there anyway of doing the message box but without the noise or icon? I had briefly experimented with that but I went with a custom box to circumvent the noise & icon.

Comment: @LukeAshford: Ah, in that case, I don't know of a good way. Doing a custom message box as you were doing is probably the right way to go

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent way too much time trying to extend a dialog, this example helped me get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an older question, but I would like to note what I use for custom dialog boxes and do not have the "noise / icon" (at least in my opinion). This is working with wxPython 2.9.5.0.

This is the code I use:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

def showConfirmDlg(message, caption, flag=wx.OK|wx.ICON_NONE):
    msg = wx.MessageDialog(None, message=message,
                       caption=caption, style=flag)
    msg.ShowModal()
    msg.Destroy()

pub.subscribe(showConfirmDlg, 'dialog.confirm')
```

As you can see in the snippet I can use this function repeatedly for various messages and eliminate the need for multiple function definitions. To show the dialog box with the text in your example I would do this:

```
def onButtonPress(self, event):
    pub.sendMessage('dialog.confirm',
        message="Forgot your password?\n Contact 'TheHiguty' (rest of text)",
        caption="Forgot Password?") # Could even just put caption=""
```

For further re-usability options you can replace the "flag=wx.OK|wx.ICON_NONE" with just "flag" and add "flag=wx.OK|(whatever style)" to your function call.

For more examples regarding Python and wxPython I highly recommend Mike Driscoll's blog site [The Mouse vs The Python.](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/)I have found it amazingly informative and have learned a lot about wxPython from Mr Driscoll.

Hope this helps you and others!

--EDIT--
I should mention that I found wx.ICON_NONE by accident while trying to remove icons from my message boxes myself.